What is the meaning of 这其中 in 如果对方还不明白这其中的信息?
日经济新闻 2024-09-22 19:12 (Beijing time)
每经编辑 黄胜
...
内塔尼亚胡威胁称，“在过去几天里，我们对真主党发动了一系列其无法想象的打击。如果对方还不明白这其中的信息，那他们终会明白的。”内塔尼亚胡还重申，“以色列将恢复北部地区安全，让当地居民返家。”
What is the meaning of 这其中 in 如果对方还不明白这其中的信息?
这 means this, here or what? Does it refer to what?
其中 means within, in, within it? Does it refer to what?
如果(if)对方(the other side)还(still)不(not)明白(understand)这其中(?)的信息(message)
How to make it make sense?

"If they don't understand the information in that (yet), then they will understand in the end." I'm guessing the original said something along the lines of "if they haven't gotten the message by now..."
It reminds me of Pontius Pilate's line in, IIRC, The Last Temptation of Christ: "There must be a thousand skulls up there by now. I do wish you would count them some time. You might learn something."

"这其中"  is point to the 打击.  => If you still don't understand why I hit you.

其中 = among (these); within/inside (it)
如果对方还不明白这其中的信息 - If the other/opposite side still does not understand "the message included within".

不明白: fail to grasp
这： refers to the "unimaginable attacks"
其中的信息: the message in our "unimaginable attacks"
在过去几天里，
In the past few days,
我们对真主党发动了一系列其无法想象的打击。
we have launched a series of unimaginable attacks on Hezbollah.
如果对方还不明白这其中的信息，那他们终会明白的。
If the other side does not (yet) grasp this message,
那他们终会明白的。
well, in the end they will understand.
只要美国人继续给我们炸弹，我们就会继续使用它们！
As long as the Americans keep giving us bombs, we will keep using them!
